# Convert gradle multi project to springboot fat jar application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I had a http servlet application which was a **multi project gradle** build, where my project was a  contain **gradle** HttpServlet project and it depends on the other two gradle java projects.  I deployed all the 3 jars in the **tomcat webapps/Web-INF/lib** directory and run it.

Now there is a requirement that I have to convert my application as a **spring boot application** and instead of 3 separate jars I have to create a **fat jar** which I should run it.

I don’t have much experience with grade and spring boot. I was wondering how can I create  a fat jar from the multi gradle project.?

I converted my http servlet project to a  spring boot project but I am confused that how I will refer the other gradle  projects in the  springboot project and create a single fat jar? Please see the directory structure of the projects

```
Rootrepository
  - Springboot project
     -src….
- OtherGardleProject1
    - Src…
- OtherGardleProject2
    - Src…
```

Can someone please share some pointer?

Comment: I think following example follow fall into my requirement https://github.com/jwilsoncredera/Profiles-Blog. Still I welcome comments.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a top-level `settings.gradle` file that includes the main app and the libraries

```
Rootrepository
  - settings.gradle 
  - Springboot project
     - build.gradle
     -src….
- OtherGardleProject1
    - Src…
- OtherGardleProject2
    - Src…
```

The `settings.gradle` looks like this:

```
include: ':Springboot project', ':OtherGardleProject1', ':OtherGardleProject2'
```

Then in the `build.gradle` of the `Springboot project` module you add the dependencies to the libraries

```
plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.3.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

...
dependencies {
  compile project(':OtherGardleProject1')
  compile project(':OtherGardleProject2')
  ...
}
```

After you build the project, the jar in `Sprinboot project/build/libs` folder should contain the classes of the app and the other two modules as jar files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was I doing previously. I was looking to create a single fat jar

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a fat jar? Add the classes of the two modules in the `BOOT-INF\classes` inside the jar?

Comment: I am not sure whether it should add in BOOT-INF but classes of other project should  add to the springboot jars

Comment: I followed the directory structure as you mentioned and able to create a fat jar using ```subprojects.each { subproject ->
  evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)
}

task mmJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
      manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'
        attributes 'Start-Class': ‘mypackage.springboot.Application'
    }
  subprojects.each { subproject ->
    from subproject.configurations.archives.artifacts.files.collect {
      zipTree(it)
    }
  }
} ```. But while running it fails with following exception

Comment: ```caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/JavaEWAH-1.1.6.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:284)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:264)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:252)```

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the way the jar is built. Instead of creating the jar yourself you should let the `spring-boot` gradle [plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) do it.

Comment: Don't I need to add build.gradle in the root repository?

Comment: I posted a followup question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56256266/exception-while-creating-a-fat-jar-for-spring-boot-application-which-depends-on

Comment: As you said, I removed the build.gradle from  the  root and  jut relied on springboot plugin to create the jar and it worked