# Exception while creating a fat jar for spring boot application which depends on other project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

This is follow up of my previous question 
*[Convert gradle multi project to springboot fat jar application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246122/convert-gradle-multi-project-to-springboot-fat-jar-application/)*

I had a http servlet application which was a multi project gradle build, where my project was a contain gradle HttpServlet project and it depends on the other two gradle java projects. I deployed all the 3 jars in the tomcat webapps/Web-INF/lib directory and run it.

Now there is a requirement that I have to convert my application as a spring boot application and instead of 3 separate jars I have to create a fat jar which I should run it.

I arranged my code as follows

```
    Rootrepository
      - settings.gradle 
     - build.gradle
      - Springboot project
         - build.gradle
         -src….
    - OtherGardleProject1
        - Src…
    - OtherGardleProject2
        - Src…

Please see `root project’s build.gradle`

version = '1.0.0'
group = ‘myproj’
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
            }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    compileJava

    jar {
     from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }
}

subprojects.each { subproject ->
  evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)
}


task mmJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
      manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'
        attributes 'Start-Class': ‘mypackage.springboot.Application'
    }
  subprojects.each { subproject ->
    from subproject.configurations.archives.artifacts.files.collect {
      zipTree(it)
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
}
```

Please see `springboot projects’ build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        spring_plugin_version = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_plugin_version")
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'



dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile project(‘:otherproject1’)


    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile('org.springframework:spring-webmvc')

    runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8')
    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Then I ran `gradle clean assemble mmJar` and it created a fat jar as expected.

But when I try to run `java -jar build/libs/myproj-1.0.0.jar`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/JavaEWAH-1.1.6.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/JavaEWAH-1.1.6.jar'
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:256)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/JavaEWAH-1.1.6.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:252)
    ... 6 more
```

Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use Spring Boot to create a fatjar don't do it youyrself. Spring Boot already gnerates an executable fatjar containing everything, you are trying to shoehorn that into another fatjar.

Comment: Did you mean my mmJar in root build.gradle is not the correct way? Could you please post it as answer using my two gradle files

Comment: Your Spring Boot (sub) project IS the fatjar... You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @M.Deinum and me in the linked post, just let spring boot gradle plugin do the the job. In your root folder keep the `settings.gradle` file and remove the `build.gradle`. Run

```
gradle clean build
```

in the `Rootrepository` folder.  Gradle will build the projects included in `settings.gradle` and create the fat jar in the `Springboot project/build/libs` folder

Comment: I removed the build.gradle in root project and ran  ./gradlew bootJar

Then I got error in my second project 
Build file ‘Otherproject1/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Otherproject1'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments ```[{group=com.google.guava, name=guava, version=18.0}] ```on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Please see the build.gradle of Otherproject1/build.gradle
dependencies {

    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'18.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.9.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

Comment: I was being silly. Forgot to add apply plugin 'java' to second project's build.gradle

Comment: yes, it' solved the issue. I checked the content of the fat jar  ( jar tf myspringboot.jar) and I can see the my otherproject1.jar in that